# Is it possible to make an index for an OR query?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a query like this:

```
select * from things where person_1_id=123 OR person_2_id=123
```

Is it possible to make some sort of index that covers this? Assume that the id (123) matched against will always be the same for both columns.

Comment: See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could try splitting it into a union and indexing the two individual columns.

Your query would be

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Things
WHERE   person_1_id = 123
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    Things
WHERE   person_2_id = 123
```

and index `person_1_id` AND `person_2_id`

Note we use a `UNION` rather than a `UNION ALL` so we don't get superflous records

**Disclaimer:**

I'm more experienced with SQL Server than any other platform, the above method can work in SQL Server but YMMV on other platforms

Comment: That's a great idea. And the amount of work ultimately done will essentially be ideal. (A small amount of O(1) overhead to do two queries and a union, but zero additional O(n) overhead for the queries themselve). I was wondering if that's what postgres would do anyway "under the hood" as long as I had an index on each column.

Comment: @JohnBachir It would probably use a BitmapOr on the two indexes under the hood, which is not quite identical and probably faster as it doesn't have to do the dedup step the slow way. A major difference is that if your table has no primary or unique keys, then the UNION is not guaranteed to return the correct result, while BitmapOr is.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE (condition1) UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE (condition2) AND NOT (condition1)` performance may be better - excess sorting is not applied. of course composite index needed.

Comment: @JohnBachir: the UNION solution will be less efficient if you have many columns (and possibly many results for each condition) in the table because the implicit DISTINCT gets more expensive. Create the indexes and test your real query using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 2):

If you create one index on each column, you should get a very efficient [combined index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) BitmapOr plan.  Try it and see, using `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

If the number of rows returned is large, then you might want to have a large setting of work_mem so that the bitmap can fit in memory and you avoid needing to remove rows by rechecks.